# Hbase Pseudo distributed mode not run in localhost

Tags: java, hbase

I try to run `hbase` pseudo distributed mode in `localhost`. But localhost bind with public address. When I put **`netstat`** command that time it shows public IP only.

```
hbase-site.xml:

hbase.master : localhost:60000

hbase.rootdir : hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase

hbase.cluster.distributed : true

hbase.zookeeper.quorum : localhost 

hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir : C:\hbase-1.0.1.1\Zookeeper

hbase.zookeeper.clientPort : 2181
```

when I used **`netstat`** command `hbase` master and `regionserver` not running in `127.0.0.1` address.

```
C:\hadoopcluster\sbin>netstat -a -n -o | find "60000"
  TCP    172.16.104.181:59249   172.16.104.181:60000   ESTABLISHED     15088
  TCP    172.16.104.181:60000   0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2320
  TCP    172.16.104.181:60000   172.16.104.181:59249   ESTABLISHED     2320
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if localhost was defined as 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file?

if you want to bind to 127.0.0.1 just specify that IP instead of 'localhost' in the config file